# How to Display Selected City in menu using PHP

Tags: php

I'm doing one search engine.in that module i have to select city at menu bar. I fetched city names from database to menu bar. If i select a particular city I have to display same thing in that menu. How to do that? help me...

```
<?php 
    $sql="SELECT DISTINCT CITY_ID,CITY_TITLE FROM CITY";
    $res=mysql_query($sql);
?>

<header>
    <nav class="headerTop">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="headerTopHolder">
                    <div class="dropdown locationDropdown">
                        <a id="bangaloreclick" class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
                            Bangalore
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down"></span>
                        </a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1" id="insideareas">
                        <?php while($cityrow=mysql_fetch_array($res)) { ?>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#"><?php echo $cityrow['CITY_TITLE'];?></a>
                            </li>
                        <?php } ?>

                        </ul>
                    </div>
```

Comment: Use "onclick" function in while loop, and assign value to div you can display selected city name on top.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean this?

```js
$('#insideareas a').on("click",function(){
  alert($(this).html())

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1" id="insideareas">
   <li><a href="#">City Name 1</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">City Name 2</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">City Name 3</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">City Name 4</a></li>
</ul>
```